# Template for initialization of the "customer class" from Nicolai Josuttis' c++17 presentation

Tags: c++, c++17

I just watched a presentation by [Nicolai Josuttis “The Nightmare of Move Semantics for Trivial Classes”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNRju6_yn3o)

In the presentation he shows how to build a "perfect customer class", so that it's constructor accepts up to all three arguments with as few mallocs as possible. Here are the solutions he presents:

```
// 11 mallocs (4cr + 7cp + 1mv)
Customer(std::string f = "", std::string l = "", int i = 0) :
    first(f), last(l), id(i) 
{}
// 5 mallocs (4cr + 1cp + 5mv)
Customer(std::string f = "", std::string l = "", int i = 0) :
    first(std::move(f)), last(std::move(l)), id(i) 
{}
// all manual combinations carefully avoiding ambiguities, such as
// 5 mallocs (4cr + 1cp + 1mv)
Customer(const std::string&, const std::string&, int i = 0);

// 5 mallocs (4cr + 1cp + 1mv)
template<typename S1, typename S2 = std::string, typename = std::enable_if<std::is_convertible_v<std::string>>
Customer(S1&& f, S2&& l = "", int i = 0):
    first(std::forward<S1>(f)), last(std::forward<S1>(l)), id(i)
{}
```

In cases like this I use an idiom (shown below), that he didn't consider in the presentation, nor did I find it elsewhere, yet I think it is suitable in both terms of performance and usage. It uses private inheritance of a struct, that has the members. The constructor template uses a parameter pack to do the job. So I wonder: is there anything wrong with this approach? Should I expect some problems in performance or usage? Any other pitfalls? Is this a known idiom that I just missed? (But why it wasn't there?)

Here is the code for the class:

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>

struct CustomerData
{
    std::string first;
    std::string last;
    int id;
};

class Customer: private CustomerData
{
public:

    // Constructor template
    template<typename... Args>
    Customer(Args... args):
        CustomerData{std::move(args)...}
    {
    }
};
```

**Edit:** 1) POD changed to struct (POD containing string is not a POD, thanks to a remark by Daniel Langr), 2) added an explanatory sentence if one doesn't want to watch the whole video

**Edit 2:** std::forward changed to std::move, thanks to remark of Jarod42

**Edit 3:** added reference code on request of apple apple

Comment: You don't use forwarding reference, your forward can be replaced by `std::move`. (You so have an "extra"-move (might be more problematic with `std::array<char, BigNumber> buffer;)` ).

Comment: Non-constrained template constructor (with forwading reference) is problematic with copy constructor.

Comment: _"It uses private inheritance of a POD"_ — `CustomerData` is not a POD class, since `std::string` is not.

Comment: @Jarod42 Actually I'm not quite sure about that, the problem is with using const char* in the constructor. That would't work with move.

Comment: `std::move` a pointer (`const char*`) is a copy (of the pointer), so you are fine.

Comment: Doesn't your CustomerData class have all the problems from the talk and your Customer class is like Vid in the talk? What happens when you add all the examples from the talk? Do they all compile? Did you look at the produced code and count the mallocs and moves?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow No it doesn't. You can verify yourself, try the examples. I tried all the combinations of std::string, const char,  r-value references and just defaults and it works fine (at least all from the vid, + I use this idiom actively and did not encounter any problem so far, but that does not mean there are none). I would't ask if it didn't work. Do you suggest to add the test code from the vid? I think it would make the post unnecessarily long.

Comment: One drawback with template version (that he doesn't mention in video neither), is that you cannot use initializer_list: `Customer c({42, 'a'}, {it1, it2}, 51);`.

Comment: `std::is_convertible<std::chrono::system_clock, Customer>{}` is `true`.

Comment: @HowardHinnant • caught at compile time, because error: `no viable conversion from 'std::chrono::system_clock' to 'std::string'`.  @JohnieWalker • I'd send your suggestion to Nicolai.  He's very approachable (and would be happy to entertain your notion), and in my experience he's likely to give you a reply quite quickly.  (And thanks for the link to the presentation, I enjoyed watching it.)

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more verbose:  `std::is_convertible<std::chrono::system_clock, Customer>{}` compiles and publicly derives from the type `true_type`.  This can cause both compile-time, and even run-time errors in your client's code.  It would be much more preferable if `std::is_convertible<std::chrono::system_clock, Customer>{}` compiled and derived from `false_type`.  To achieve that, you would need some type of constraint on the template argument `Args...`.

Comment: @JohnieWalker can you please include the code you're comparing to?

Comment: @appleapple Please check out the video in 48-th minute, there is a slide for it where you see all the cases. The code is too long for a comment. But essentially the challenge is to create a customer class with the data members shown in CustomerData, that is "perfect" in terms of both performance and usability.

Comment: @JohnieWalker I mean it should be [edit] into the question so it's self contained, so we don't need to go to other site (which may not even exist after some time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
template <typename Args>
Customer(Args... args) :
CustomerData{std::move(args)...}
{
}
```

is comparable to

```
Customer(std::string first, std::string last = "", int id = -1) :
    first(std::move(first)), last(std::move(last)), id(id)
{}
```

(Which is the preferred variant from the video, but not the most efficient, as there is some (up to 4) extra move constructor)

Default values (which is also a concern in the video) can be handled directly in your data structure.

Performance are the same.

Your version is less verbose, but also less self documenting.

As for most template (forwarding reference in particular),
it disallows initializer_list (test case not used/shown in the video):

```
Customer c({42, 'a'}, {it1, it2}, 51);
```

Your version is not SFINAE friendly: `std::is_constructible_v<Customer, float, std::vector<int>>` would give incorrect answer.

In the same way, example from video about inheritance:

```
Vip vip{/*..*/}; 
Customer c(vip); // Would select wrongly you constructor
```

You can add SFINAE/`requires` to handle those cases though.

I would compare with another alternative

```
template <typename... Args>
requires(is_aggregate_constructible_v<CustomerData, Args&&...>)
Customer(Args&&... args) : CustomerData{std::forward<Args>(args)...}
{
}
```

which would be comparable to

```
template <typename S1, typename S2 = std::string>
requires (std::is_constructible_v<std::string, S1&&>
          && std::is_constructible_v<std::string, S2&&>)
Customer(S1&& first, S2&& last = "", int id = -1) :
    first(std::forward<S1>(first)),
    second(std::forward<S2>(second)),
    id(id),
{}
```

The most efficient alternative.

Again,

- Same performance
- less verbose and potentially less self documenting.

Here, both versions are template, and both versions have the issue with the construction with the initializer list.

To conclude, your version without `requires` has some pitfalls.

If you add the `requires`, then going to the proposed alternative (forwarding reference instead of by value) would be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

When I extend the example with a "logging string"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

class CustomString {
public:
    CustomString(const char *) {
        std::cout << "CustomString(const char*)\n"; }
    CustomString(const std::string &) {
        std::cout << "CustomString(const std::string&)\n"; }
    CustomString(std::string &&) {
        std::cout << "CustomString(std::string&&)\n"; }

    CustomString(const CustomString &) {
        std::cout << "CustomString(const CustomString&)\n"; }
    CustomString(CustomString &&) {
        std::cout << "CustomString(CustomString&&)\n"; }
};

struct CustomerData
{
    CustomString first;
    CustomString last;
    int id;
};

class Customer: private CustomerData
{
public:

    // Constructor template
    template<typename... Args>
    Customer(Args... args):
        CustomerData{std::move(args)...}
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "John Doe\n";
    Customer c{"John", "Doe", 1};
    std::cout << "Jane\n";
    CustomString jane{"Jane"};
    std::cout << "Jane Doe\n";
    Customer d{jane, "Doe", 1};
    std::cout << "move Jane Doe\n";
    Customer e{std::move(jane), "Doe", 1};
}
```

it gives this output

```
John Doe
CustomString(const char*)
CustomString(const char*)
Jane
CustomString(const char*)
Jane Doe
CustomString(const CustomString&)
CustomString(CustomString&&)
CustomString(const char*)
move Jane Doe
CustomString(CustomString&&)
CustomString(CustomString&&)
CustomString(const char*)
```

In the second and third example, you can see an additional move, which doesn't happen in the talk's version. This might or might not make a (small) difference.